# How to make a 3d model from a sofa

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, texture

I have a sofa.  The blue area is what I want to make a 3d model from. I want to make a UV map from it and apply a texture on it.

To do so, I think first I need to make a 3d model from this area.
Am I right? If so, how can I make a 3d model from it? If I'm wrong, could you tell me what the steps are and how it's done?

Comment: I'm going to assume that this is related to your other question. It's great that you're searching for other avenues when no one answered your other question, but this is only going to complicate things. --- The reason why I  personally never answered your other question was that you never really gave proper answers to the questions I asked you. You just danced around what I asked and gave vague answers.

Comment: Your image appears to have disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't have a big 3d background-experience but you may be able to use Illustrator to render some basic 3d shapes on top of a (for positionion only) copy of the scene and then apply surface texture. Use a little photoshop magic to marry the two seemlessly. That's how I'd go about creating a mock up of that image with custom textures... if that was your goal I am not sure.